# There is an HTML2Jade converter, is there a JADE2HTML converter

Tags: html, pug

I am looking at a code-base from Google which includes `JADE (PUG) templates`, and want to convert the `JADE code back` to **plain old HTML** as part of a larger refactor.
I see a couple libs for `HTML->JADE` but none for `JADE->HTML`.

Is there a `JADE->HTML` converter out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what Jade (Pug) does:

http://jade-lang.com/command-line

```
$ jade < my.jade > my.html
```